# TomEE throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, tomcat, java-ee-6, vaadin, openejb

I am trying to deploy a Vaadin/JEE6 application to TomEE.

The following exception is thrown during deployment:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapp]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1370)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1242)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1389)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at org.apache.openejb.tomcat.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadWebModule(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:892)
    at org.apache.openejb.tomcat.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:879)
    at org.apache.openejb.tomcat.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:416)
    at org.apache.openejb.tomcat.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:377)
    at org.apache.openejb.tomcat.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    ... 15 more
```

I must admit I've no idea why this exception may be thrown. Before digging into the TomEE code, I would like to ask if anyone here ever stumbled across this exception and could give me a hint where to look for errors.

Comment: Look like OpenEJB bug or misconfiguration. It's at least a bug in OpenEJB that not a more informal exception is been thrown as to why that list could possibly be empty.

Comment: Looks like no web-modules are recognized-

    private void loadWebModule(AppModule appModule, StandardContext standardContext) {
        WebModule webModule = appModule.getWebModules().get(0);

Comment: A rough guess - is the web-app a no web.xml webapp ? You can check for any warnings by setting these system properties: openejb.validation.skip=false
openejb.validation.output.level=VERBOSE

Comment: Yes, it is a no web.xml webapp.

Comment: Setting the properties in catalina.sh did not log any extra info.

Comment: I think [TomEE-27](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-27) adds support to recognize no web.xml webapps (beta-2, trunk code)
Can you try with web.xml placed ?

Comment: I tried adding WEB-INF/web.xml but as soon as there's a web.xml, the EJBContainer in my unit tests refuses to start with the message "couldn't start owb context".

Comment: moved the discussion to [chat here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5354/discussion-between-stratwine-and-codebrickie) as SO suggests..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to be a combination of buggy beta-1 and buggy project setup. See [TomEE-51](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-51?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) for details.